# How do I load image to React from Django REST API?

Tags: python, reactjs, django

So as stated, I'm having trouble loading images from Django backend(fetch works fine). I've looked other similar questions, but NONE OF THEM HELPED, sadly.
So here's my Django code:
settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

model.py

```
class Content(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='None', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, null=True, blank=True)
    key_line = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I've uploaded an image named 'eeee.PNG' via admin, and I can see the data serialized in JSON format like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "image": "/media/None/eeee.PNG",
        "key_line": "key.",
        "body": "blablabla",
    },
]
```

And my React code (fetch has been successfully worked) :

```
<Container classname="">
     <Row className="">
         <Col className="text-text img-eachcake">{this.props.image}</Col>
         <Col className="text-text img-eachcake" src={this.props.image}></Col>
     </Row>
</Container>
```

As you can see, I've tried two ways but none of them worked. What do you think is the problem? All the other `props` are loaded fine. It's just the image file that doesn't work.

+in the inspection mode > Elements, I see the line as : `<div src="/media/None/eeee.PNG" class="text-text img-eachcake col"></div>`

Comment: Can you try changing the upload_to path? may be upload_to = 'images/' in Content model

Comment: Oh, you mean change the path to `images`?

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue. Nobody is talking about fetching the image from Django backend.  Everywhere there are post on Image Upload.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your image URL,

```
"image": "/media/None/eeee.PNG",
```

This should have domain or localhost before `/media` on which your Django project is working
Like:

```
"image": "localhost:8000/media/None/eeee.PNG"
```

and if you're running on server this Django project `localhost:8000` should replace with domain

So Problem is in your serializer data way, You're using the wrong way to serialize data because the image URL is not serializing according to your question.

Use a proper Django REST framework serializer to serialize your data.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Kindly answer how to do fix the serializer. As the documentation doesn't have anything related to ImageField.

Comment: Use default ModelSerializer, it'll handle automatic this for Image field.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clarfy Neeraj's answer:

- instead of sending

  "image": "localhost:8000/media/None/eeee.PNG"
- try:

  "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/None/eeee.PNG"

Since Django redirects automatically to your media folder. Remember the IP and Port may change depending on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
`http://localhost:8000${this.props.image}`
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This how I did mine, this solution works if anyone still having issues with this same question.

````
class Image(models.Model):
   image_file = models.ImageField()

   @property
   def get_image_url(self) -> str:
      if self.image_file and hasattr(self.image_file, 'url'):
         return f"http://localhost:8000{self.image_file.url"
```.

Image_file is the image file in the model class and the property function also belong to the same class. So knsdI hope this helps because it work for me.
````